# ftp one line connection

Tags: debian, ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to connect to my Filezilla server (ms windows host) from command line under Debian 8.

I searched for documentation and saw plenty of tutorials saying that a good way to connect to a server in one line with credentials is:

`ftp -in ftp://myusername:mypasswd@ip.v4.addr.here`

When I run this command, ftp do not connect and I get the following error:

`ftp: ftp://myusername:mypasswd@ip.v4.addr.here: Name or service not known`

Does anybody know what's wrong here ? Do I have to specify any port or something ? (the server is listening on port 21)

My goal is to write a short bash script that would upload a specific file. I only miss the connection part `:\`

Thank you !

Comment: Are you able to FTP to the host interactively, by using `ftp ${IPADDRESS}`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes sir, and it works like a charm !

Comment: I wonder if that's even possible ..

Comment: I checked out `ftp`'s man page, and it doesn't appear to support what you're trying to do.  `lftp`, however, can, and if you are _downloading_ a file, `curl` and `wget` can.

Comment: Thank you for your researches. Seeing such a syntax on different places, I thought that may be man did not mention all capabilities. In fact, it does `:p`. By the way .. Is lftp installed by default ?

Comment: No, but it's in most repositories; `apt-get install lftp` or `yum install lftp` depending on if you're using a Red Hat or Debian-derived distro; if it's Arch, some invocation of `pacman` would do the trick.

Comment: The ancient and primitive `ftp` client is what you have to use on archaic systems where you don't have any other choice.  On modern systems, or on any system where you can either install it as a package or have the privs and resources to compile and install the source code, use `lftp` as @DopeGhoti suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I used to write ftp script all of the time!  Very old school.  As misled by others here, FTP is designed to work as a batch script and just because it's archaic doesn't mean it doesn't work.  Ftp and vsftp is highly insecure because your id/password is sent clear text over the network. This is why people us sftp or scp (which uses the SSH protocol). But, if clear text passwords over a network is not a concern for your environment, e.g. it's a closed network, ftp is a valid option and a bit easier to set up and maintain than services using ssh.

This is an example script below:

`#!/bin/bash
ftp -nv myservernameorip << EOF
quote USER myuserid
quote PASS mypasswd
binary
ls
put some_files
get some_files
quit
EOF`

Just replace 'myservernameorip', 'myuserid' and 'mypasswd' with the real host name / IP, and account information; as well as change the `ls`, `put` and/or `get` command 'some_files' with real file paths.

Comment: Thank you ! The backup server is located on the private network .. I figured out that I can configure my online backup ftp service in a way that I wont have to specify my credentials when I try to connect from my server. The authentication process only grant access to my ip ! `:)` Furthermore only ftp is allowed (so no ssh based ftp clients !)

Comment: An upvote would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: +1 for both your time and testimony `:p`